# Bulk stop watching tickets on Lighthouse?

Tags: lighthouse

Via the [Lighthouse](http://lighthouseapp.com) user interface, is there any way to *bulk* stop watching tickets?

I have more than 150 tickets on a project I want to stop watching, and would just as soon not go into each and every one of them. I thought the bulk edit command might work, but there doesn't appear to be a `watch` keyword in the [bulk edit](http://help.lighthouseapp.com/faqs/ticket-workflow/ticket-keyword-updates) stuff (which is fair enough, I'm not really *editing* the tickets). When I go to my profile, I can subscribe or unsubscribe to an entire project, but I'm not seeing a way to do this at the (bulk) ticket level. Looking at a list of the tickets I'm watching, I'm not seeing a way to do anything to all of them (other than the bulk edit command of course). Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: BTW, I figured this was a programming question rather than a superuser question (it would be the first Lighthouse-related superuser question), but I'm prepared to be shot down and moved over if most people disagree. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Their support staff say](http://help.lighthouseapp.com/discussions/questions/569-is-there-a-way-to-bulk-stop-watching-tickets) there is no way to stop watching tickets in bulk. Apparently it's been requested for a future version.